# Customize eclipse new class template

Tags: java, eclipse, templates

I want Eclipse to put following comments when ever I create a new class. How to create a template like this?

```
// ===========================================================
// Constants
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================
// Fields
// ===========================================================


// ===========================================================
// Constructors
// ===========================================================



// ===========================================================
// Getter & Setter
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================
// Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces
// ===========================================================



// ===========================================================
// Methods
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================
// Inner and Anonymous Classes
// ===========================================================
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Window - Preferences - Java - Code Style - Code Templates - Class Body - Edit

Typing "Templates" in the search box above the tree of the preferences window is a good way to find what you're looking for